# Default Environment Variables, and VM options for all new projects in Intellij

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I want to apply common env variables and vm options for all my spring boot applications in Intellij.
Whenever i open a new project, the config should copy automatically.
Is there a way to do this?

Also , can i use vmoptions file for supplying my default vm arguments ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use vmoptions for it, that configures the VM options for IntelliJ itself (as IntelliJ is actually written in Java).

Open the templates section in the run configurations dialog.

[image: Templates Menu]

Scroll down until you find the run configuration you want to set the defaults for (in this case `Sprint Boot`).

[image: Spring Boot menu]

Click on it, and anything put into the fields will be used for *new* configurations. Note that it is not possible to retroactively change settings for existing configurations. In this case, what you want is in the `Environment` dropdown to configure VM options.

[image: Environment dropdown]

Manage the configurations, hit OK, and all your new configurations will have those applied to them by default.

Comment: Thanks you SirNapkin1334, i will try it and update you with my results

Comment: can i use this template in my new projects ?

Comment: Yes, I believe you can. Go to File -> New Projects Settings -> Run Configuration Templates for New Projects, and that will bring up the same menu, where you can make changes that will be adapted for all new projects.